# Join two tables gone wrong, I'm really stuck

Tags: mysql, join, prestashop

I have two tables (mysql), with these fields:

First table `ps_cart_product`:

- `id_cart`,
- `id_product`,
- `quantity` (this is a numeric field, containing the number of product ordered)
- ...

Second Table `ps_product`:

- `id_product`,
- `reference`,
- ...

I need to obtain the 'quantity' field that contain (given a certain id_cart from the first table) the quantity ordered for each product that have the field 'reference' in the second table value 'ticket'.
Then I have to 'sum' the fields values of the returning rows.

This is the sql code that I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.quantity
FROM ps_cart_product cp 
JOIN  ps_product p ON cp.id_cart = 84
AND p.reference = "ticket"
```

The result is wrong... this query throw all field (3 rows) that have the field with value 'ticket', instead of giving only the 2 field that have the 'AND' condition, which is the result I want.
Any suggestion?
Anyway, this is a Prestashop db.

Comment: You are missing the `WHERE` part?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. Can you please add some sample data from the two tables with the desired output, it will be very helpful explaining what are you trying to do.

Comment: Ok, now i get this result: two rows (the "quantity" field) with the value of "7" and "3", which is the number of product that I have in the order  "cart". The problem is that it throw also the rows who don't have the "AND" condition to "ticket" in the other table. There is only one product with the value "ticket" in the order cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is missing the `JOIN` condition between the two tables.

```
select DISTINCT cp.quantity
from ps_cart_product cp
inner join ps_product  p
  on cp.id_product = p.id_product -- < this is missing
where p.reference = 'ticket'
  and cp.id_cart = 84
```

Then if you want to `sum()` the quantity, you can use:

```
select sum(cp.quantity) TotalQuantity
from ps_cart_product cp
inner join ps_product  p
  on cp.id_product = p.id_product
where p.reference = 'ticket'
  and cp.id_cart = 84
```

Comment: It seems to work... I'm really a newbie in sql, that is for sure.

Comment: @user1924288 When you join tables you have to state what column the tables are joined on.  If you need help learning join syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks! Cause in "joins" I'm really a zero... I have to study, sigh

Comment: Thanks, you were really really helpful, I have lost many time trying to get this result, you just 1 minute. :)

Comment: @user1924288 You are welcome! Don't get frustrated it takes time to learn this stuff! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the where clause at the end to specify the ID. The purpose of the join is the match tables on identical records, based on a value given in the where clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.quantity
FROM ps_cart_product cp 
INNER JOIN  ps_product p ON cp.id_cart = p.id_product
AND p.reference = "ticket"
Where cp.id_cart = 84
```